# IIS_IUSRS cannot access files uploaded and created by Network Service - error 401.3

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

Let me rephrase my question as I investigated further:

**The problem:**

I have a php script that is used to upload images on my windows webserver 2008. The files are created in the correct directory. The are created and owned by the user `Network Service`. `Network Service` has full access to the uploaded file.

As soon as I try to access the uploaded file (mostly an image) via HTTP, I get an `401.3 not authorized` error.

Now, if I right-click on the not accessible image and grant `IIS_IUSRS` group read permissions via the security tab, the image can be accessed! By default `IIS_IUSRS` has NO access at all for the uploaded file.

The directory containing the image files has the correct access rights set. But each file that is new uploaded to the directory is permitted for `IIS_IUSRS`.

**The question:**

How can I grant `IIS_IUSRS` by default access to the newly uploaded file? The appPool of the website has its identity set to its default, I also tried setting it to "networkIdentity" or so, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fine solution: [http://sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/fixing-wordpress-image-upload-on-a-windows-server-permissions-problem/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170525150238/http://sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/fixing-wordpress-image-upload-on-a-windows-server-permissions-problem/)

To summarize:
Give your IUSR account Modify permissions for the `C:/Windows/Temp/` directory and restart the IIS site. Or you could modify where php writes to using the php.ini by overwriting the `upload_tmp_dir` value which may be more preferable over letting a web application write to the `C:/Windows/` directory.